# How to show select option that haven't selected in jquery using laravel

Tags: laravel

How to show select option that haven't selected in jquery using laravel ??
Example, in index 0 i choose slot id G05B-IA7 and when i click add more, the G05B-IA7 slot code option does not appear because it has been selected at index 0

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9q0l.png)

My code in view

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <label>Pilih Pallet : </label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
         <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-portrait"></i></span>
    </div>
    <select class="form-control" id="slot_id" name="slot_id[]"><option>-- Pilih Pallet --</option></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jquery for show slot id

```
$('#warehouse').change(function(){
      var warehouseid = $(this).val(); 
      if(warehouseid){
          $.ajax({
              type:"GET",
              url:"/admin-master/get_slot_id?warehouseid="+warehouseid,
              dataType: 'JSON',
              success:function(res){        
              if(res){
                  $("#slot_id").empty();
                  $.each(res,function(id_slot,id_slot){
                      $("#slot_id").append(
                        '<option value="'+id_slot+'">'+id_slot+'</option>'
                      );
                  });
              }else{
                     $("#slot_id").empty();
              }
              }
          });
      }else{
              $("#slot_id").empty();
      }      
  });
```

My code view add more

```
              '<div class="col-md-5">' + 
                '<label>Pilih Pallet : </label>' +
                '<div class="input-group mb-3">' +
                  '<div class="input-group-prepend">' +
                    '<span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-portrait"></i></span>' +
                  '</div>' +
                  '<select id="slot_id'+i+'" class="form-control" name="slot_id['+i+']"></select>' +
                '</div>' +
              '</div>' +
```

Soryy if my english is bad

Comment: $("#slot_id").append(
                        '<option value="'+id_slot+'" selected>'+id_slot+'</option>'
                      );

Comment: Just add jquery selected, i hope it will work

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that I don't want to display the selected option